# .gitignore not ignoring specified folder

Tags: git

I'm trying to set up `.gitignore` but having issues. I have a directory `flask-test` that contains the sub directories `app`, `tmp` and `flask`. I want to ignore the `flask` directory. I init a new repository inside `flask-test`:

```
git init
git remote add origin https://github.com/username/flask-test.git
```

I then create the .gitignore:

```
sudo nano .gitignore
```

The contents of `gitignore` are like so:

```
flask
```

Is this correct? ^ or should it be `flask/`?

I then add, commit all the files and push:

```
git add .
git commit -m "First commit"
git push -u origin master
```

However when I check the repository the '.gitignore' file is not there. I then tried adding it after like so:

```
git add .gitignore
git commit -m "Adding gitignore" .gitignore
git push
```

Now this file is inside my repository however the `flask` directory is still there. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't you say `flask/*` or `flask/`?

Comment: Wait. What do you mean the ignore file isn't there? It is `.gitignore` with a leading period `.` and hence only visible when you do `ls -a`

Comment: It looks as if you did things in a different order from what you described. In particular, it looks as if you did `git add .` before `nano .gitignore`. Are you sure you did things in the order as you wrote in your question? It makes a difference.

Comment: 1. If an item (in that case - the folder) is already in git, adding it to the ignore list will not due and you'll need to perform **git rm** to remove it.
2. it should be flask/* since a folder is not a GIT object, only the files in it.

Comment: Why sudo???????

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to ignore folders you have to use the `**`.

For example if you wish to ignore the Debug & Release folder in any deepth:

```
**/Debug/
**/Release/
```

This will ignore any folder with this name regardless of the current location in the folder

Comment: I don't think this is accurate. Just the name followed by `/` has always been sufficient for me, e.g. putting `__pycache__/` in .gitignore for Python projects. The leading `**` works the same, but isn't necessary.

Comment: You need the ** if you want to ignore inner folders as well and not only the most top one, its also a best practice since you know you refer to folders instead of files.

Comment: The `/` is sufficient to distinguish folders... and AFAICT the `**` simply isn't needed, see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/tangledhelix/9da5a314fffe22e3f3f2dcbe5342be68) for an example. Now, `**` does have uses, e.g. `/foo/**/bar` there would be no other way to ignore any `bar/` hiding in the tree under `/foo/` - but I am talking about this case, where you match a directory name regardless of where it occurs.